# Query table including selfreference childs

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry for the vague title, I didn't know how to parse it correctly.
I have to 2 tables, `Uses` and `Applications` one-to-many, and Users references itself.
User can be `Dealer` or `Manager`, 1 dealer with many managers.
Currently I can get all the applications by  `UserID` but I couldn't figure out how to include the childs if user is `Dealer`. What I mean is if user is `Manager` then get his applications but if is `Dealer` get his applications including his childs applications.
EDIT:
`RoleID=1 // Dealer`
`RoleID=2 // Manager`

Here my models

```
    public class User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string DealerName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(150)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
        public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
        public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string PostalAddress { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public int? RoleID { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public string Signature { get; set; }
        public int? ParentUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual User ParentUser { get; set; }
        public virtual List<User> ChildUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual List<UserCategory> UserCategories { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Application
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationStatusID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationStatus ApplicationStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int ProductsQuantity { get; set; }
        public Application()
        {
            Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is what I am working on

```
using (var context = new ClientDbContext())
                {
                    IQueryable<Application> query;
                    if (model.UserID > 0 && model.ApplicationStatusID > 0)
                        query = context.Applications
                            .Include(x => x.ApplicationStatus)
                            .Include(x => x.Products)
                            .Where(x => x.UserID == model.UserID && x.ApplicationStatusID == model.ApplicationStatusID && x.Enabled == true);
                    else if (model.UserID == 0 && model.ApplicationStatusID > 0)
                        query = context.Applications
                            .Include(x => x.ApplicationStatus)
                            .Include(x => x.Products)
                            .Where(x => x.ApplicationStatusID == model.ApplicationStatusID && x.Enabled == true);
                    else if (model.UserID > 0 && model.ApplicationStatusID == 0)
                        query = context.Applications
                            .Include(x => x.ApplicationStatus)
                            .Include(x => x.Products)
                            .Where(x => x.UserID == model.UserID && x.Enabled == true);

                    else
                        query = null;
                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        item.ProductsQuantity = item.Products.Count();
                    }
                    response = new UtilitariesResponse<Application>(config).setResponseBaseForList(query);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement:

> if user is Manager then get his applications but if is Dealer get his applications including his childs applications.

I'm not certain whether you are using entity framework or not. If so, you are making your life more difficult because you deviate from the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx)

You say that every User has zero or more ChildUsers, and every User has zero or one ParentUser, referred by the foreign key ParentUserId.

Similarly there is a one-to-many relation between Users and Applications: every User has zero or more Applications, every Application belongs to exactly one User, referred to by the foreign key UserId.

The proper way to write these relations in Entity Framework would be:

```
class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}

    // every User has zero or more Applications (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications {get; set;}

    // every User has zero or more ChildUsers (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<User> ChildUsers {get; set}

    // every User belongs to zero or one ParentUser, using foreign key
    public int ParentUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User ParentUser {get; set;}

    ... // all other properties are not important in your question.
}
```

> if user is Manager then get his applications but if is Dealer get his applications including his childs applications.

If the user is a manager, how do you want the applications with the Child Applications: as one sequence of Applications, or as one sequence of Applications where every Application has zero or more ChildApplications?

It's not important how you decide whether the user is a manager or not, let's assume the user has a property:

```
public bool IsManager {get => ...}

IQueryable<User> Users = ClientDbContext.Users
    // only if you don't want all Users:
    .Where(user => ...)
```

The idea is, to make two groups of Users: the managers and the others. If the user is not a manager, we'll select the requested properties,inclusive the applications; if the user is a Manager, we'll Select also the child applications.

```
var result = Users.Select(user => new
{
   // Select the properties that both Managers and Others need:
   Id = user.Id,
   Name = user.Name
   ...

   Applications = User.Applications.Select(application => new
   {
       // Select the application properties that you plan to use:
       Id = application.Id,
       ...

       // not needed: you already know the value
       // UserId = application.UserId,
    },

    // if the user is a Manager, add the ChildApplications, otherwise add empty collection
    ChildApplications = (User.IsManager ?
        User.ChildUsers.SelectMany(childUser => childUser.Applications) :
        Enumerable.Empty<Application>())
        .Select(childApplication => new
        {
            // select the properties that you want from the child application
        })
        .ToList(),
});
```

Look at the part:

```
ChildApplications = (User.IsManager ?
    User.ChildUsers.SelectMany(childUser => childUser.Applications) :
    Enumerable.Empty<Application>())
```

This part checks if the User is a manager. Is so, it takes all Applications from all ChildUsers as one big sequence (SelectMany instead of Select). If the User is not a Manager, he takes an empty collection of Applications.

From every Application in the result (either a collection of all Applications of ChildUsers, or an empty Collection), we select the properties that you want.

Although this works, it is not very efficient, because IsManager is called once per application. Consider making two Queries: one for the Managers and one for the others. Do not execute the Query, but Select the same properties and Concat the queries. Then execute them, so you can be certain your DBMS is contacted only once.